# How to call or insert editor inside an article in joomla 3

Tags: php, joomla3.0

Currently, i am working on the project that interact via documents. More specifically, registered users can send a letter to the administrator. So there would be title of the text and the main body(same text). When the users press a send button, a letter will send to the administrator. How can i do that?
Should i download some kind of extension of joomla?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to do it using PHP I would recommend you to use "Jumi" component for Joomla 3. That component allows you to write PHP code inside a module.

URL: http://es.2glux.com/projects/jumi

I would recommend you to test it and try to program it by yourself. Currently I don't know any modules or component that allows you to do that process.

Regards.

Comment: How do i get some guidelines  about "Jumi"!

Comment: It's pretty straightforward, just download it, upload it as another module or component in your Joomla and then you only have to go to "Components" > "Jumi" and create "New". Here you are some guides:  http://2glux.com/projects/jumi/overview

Comment: You are welcome Mike, If you have any questions regarding that you can edit the first message of leave a comment if you want. If you found my answer positive, can you check my answer as accepted? Thanks Mike and I hope you can achieve that.